# Java setShape() method giving error on command prompt but works fine on eclipse

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe

I am trying to change the shape of my main frame using

```
    frame.setShape(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(1,1,863,590,80,80));
```

this method is working perfectly on  eclipse but when I compile the program using command prompt with javac command it gives me error.

**Code Snippet**

```
C:\Users\AbdulMoiz\Desktop\JAVA PROJECT FINAL>javac Main.java
Main.java:40: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method setShape(java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D.Double)
location: class javax.swing.JFrame
frame.setShape(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(1,1,863,590,80,80));
```

**Imports**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.*;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be your eclipse isn't using the same compiler version as javac from cmd.
you can compare the javac -version result (in cmd) to the version used in the eclipse project properties.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently [JFrame.setShape](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setShape%28java.awt.Shape%29) has been introduced with JDK7 but was not available in [JDK6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html). So it looks like you are using eclipse with JDK >= 7, however your command line javac stems from a JDK <= 6.